# $\omega$-continuity and Scott continuity

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

In a recent lecture I've been presented with the concept of $\omega$-continuity, defined as "the preservation of joins in $\omega$-chains", where an $\omega$-chain is a non-empty sequence $\{a_n\}$ of elements $a_i \in \mathcal L$, where $\mathcal L$ is a complete lattice, such that $a_{i}\leq a_{i+1}$.

That is, $F : \mathcal L \to \mathcal L$ is $\omega$-continuous if for all $\omega$-chains $\{a_n\}$:

$$ \bigvee_n F(a_n) = F\Big(\bigvee_n a_n\Big) $$

---

This property was used, during the lecture, to describe Kleene's fixed point theorem. I didn't find much about this property online, and when I read about the theorem from other sources, a different definition of continuity was used: Scott continuity.

My **first questions** are:

- Is $\omega$-continuity a special case of Scott-continuity, or are they the same?
- If there is any, what would be an example of a function that is Scott-continuous but not $\omega$-continuous?

---

The **second part** of this question is more of a question of *"how would I go about proving that a function is $\omega$-continuous?"*

- What would be an example of a function that is not join-preserving in general but is $\omega$-continuous?
- What is the proof that the above function is $\omega$-continuous?

Comment: With the definition as presented, it seems like a function is $\omega$-continuous iff it preserves arbitrary non-empty joins. But I suspect that you're missing some restriction about what is a $\omega$-chain.

Comment: @amrsa quoting the notes: "an $\omega$-chain in $\mathcal L$ is a sequence of elements $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathcal L$ such that $a_i \leq a_{i + 1}$. Equivalently, it is a non-empty, linearly ordered countable set"

Comment: @amrsa: I think that the definition given is correct. It does not imply that $F$ preserves joins. To see that $F$ need not preserve arbitrary joins of chains consider $L=\omega_1^+$ and $F\colon L\to L$ defined by $F(\omega_1)=\omega_1$ and $F(x)=0$ if $x\neq \omega_1$. This $F$ is $\omega$-continuous but not Scott continuous. To see that $F$ need not preserve even pairwise joins, let $L$ be two parallel copies of $\omega_1^+$ identified at the tops and bottoms. Let $F(\textrm{top})=\textrm{top}$ and $F(x)=\textrm{bottom}$ otherwise.

Comment: @KeithKearnes If I understood your example correctly, that is more or less my point. You seem to assume (and I agree that that's very reasonable) that a $\omega$-chain is a chain indexed by the ordinal $\omega$. Perhaps that should be understood, and it is my bad. But that's what I was meaning with "restriction about what a $\omega$-chain is".